# How to tag a row if at least one column is greater than a specific value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame as follows;

| Unique ID | Value_1 | Value 2 | Value 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 10 | 50 | 18 |
| 222 | 5 | 8 | 2 |
| 333 | 12 | 3 | 5 |

I want a new column in the pandas data frame and create a tag (1) , if at least one of columns from `Value_1` to `Value_3` is greater than 10.

The output desired as follows;

| Unique ID | Value_1 | Value 2 | Value 3 | Column_tag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 10 | 50 | 18 | 1 |
| 222 | 5 | 8 | 2 | 0 |
| 333 | 12 | 3 | 5 | 1 |

I tried following code which resulted an error:

```py
def flag_df_new(df):
    
    if (df[df.columns[2:]]>10).any(axis=1):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
    
customer_summary_1['Flag'] = customer_summary_1.apply(flag_df_new, axis = 1)
```

The result I am getting:

> ```
> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a boolean expression on each column:

```
df['tag'] = ((df['Value_1']>10) | (df['Value_2']>10) | (df['Value_3'] > 10)).astype(int)
df
```

If you want to do that on an arbitrary number of columns this could work
`df['tag'] = (df[df.columns[1:]] > 10).any(axis=1)`

Answer (score 0):

Filter `Value*` columns to check them for the needed condition:

```
df['tag'] = (df.filter(like='Value') > 10).any(axis=1).astype(int)
```

---

```
   Unique ID  Value_1  Value 2  Value 3  tag
0        111       10       50       18    1
1        222        5        8        2    0
2        333       12        3        5    1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```py
# import pandas as pd
# df = pd.read_html('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75897954')[0] # scraped from your q

valCols = [c for c in df.columns if c.startswith('Value')]
df['Flag'] = df[valCols].apply(lambda r: int(any(v>10 for v in r)), axis='columns')
```

> [image: opdf]

---

The reason for your error was that when you pass a function to [`.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), it's not called with the DataFrame as a parameter, but on each of its columns [or each of its rows, if you specify *`axis='columns'`* as above (or *`axis=1`* as you did)]. It might have worked if you had defined it as

```py
# flag_df_new = lambda df_row: 1 if any(v>10 for v in df_row[1:]) else 0 ## same as
def flag_df_new(df_row):
    return 1 if any(v>10 for v in df_row[1:]) else 0
```